# Select rows where one value in field name occured in multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Suppose I have a database structure like this.

Table `users`

```
id    name    
1     Name1   
2     Name2   
3     Name3   
4     Name4
```

And another table `logs`

```
id    userid
1     1
2     1      
3     2
4     3
5     3
6     3
7     4
8     4
9     4
```

Now if I enter 3 in text box and press submit then in the server side PHP I need to fetch and display records from `users` table with `id` 3 and 4 i.e., Name3 and Name4 from `users` table as in `logs` table they occurred 3 times each. Similarly, if I press 2 and submit it should fetch and display record Name1 as `id` 1 from `users` table has occurred 2 times in logs table. What should be the query here for this? I don't understand how to start with this so I cannot post what I have tried. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query, it is working

```
select name from users where id in (select userid from logs  group by userid having count(userid) = '".$inputvalue."')
```

[DEMO LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b79a9/4/0)

Comment: it will count all userid column not grouped users.

Comment: My favorite answer. You select names from the users table and have criteria where it belongs: in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @SayedMohdAli you edited it later and added group by inside the sub-query ... Now obviously it would be fine

Comment: Worked exactly as I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Group by users and take only those groups having the count of records you input

```
select u.name
from users u
join logs l on l.userid = u.id
group by u.name
having count(l.id) = $inputValue
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27e87f/1)

Comment: Group by needs to be on 'l.userid' and by this, obviously, you will have to change select list. So rebuild the query.

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: @Muhammad Waheed: It would be very strange if `name` were not unique in the users table. If it were, then the requested query result would render rather meaningless, because with two users named equally we wouldn't know which it is. (Besides: even if we grouped by `id` we could still select `name` as the latter is functionally dependent on the former.)

Comment: @juergend now you got it ? Thorsten exactly you are right

Comment: @Muhammad Waheed: well, ... actually, what I'm saying is supporting juergen d's statement, not yours.

Comment: Isn't it strange to say "two user can't have same name" . ID is already added for the purpose of uniqueness in the table. If it is so, then must have defined a unique constraint on username.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

```
Select u.name 
from ( select userid,count(*) as NoOfRecords 
       from logs 
       group by userid 
       having count(*) = $inputvalue ) as a
inner join users u on a.userid = u.id
```